# Bundling javascript files not working

Tags: javascript

I have two files one uses the function from another, in my case `autocomplete.js` uses the function `timeAgo`. This is the autocomplete file:

```
autocomplete('.search-input', {
    templates: {
        footer: '<div class="powered-by-algolia"><div class="pull-right"><img src="/imagecache/xs/Algolia_logo_bg-white.jpg" /></div></div>'
      }
    },
    [{
      source: autocomplete.sources.hits(players, { hitsPerPage: 5 }),
      displayKey: 'first_name',
      templates: {
        header: '<div class="aa-suggestions-category"><span>Players</span></div>',
        suggestion: function(suggestion) {
          var birthday = suggestion.birthday;
          var birthdayArray = birthday.split('/');
          var age = function (birthDay, birthMonth, birthYear) {
            todayDate = new Date();
            todayYear = todayDate.getFullYear();
            todayMonth = todayDate.getMonth();
            todayDay = todayDate.getDate();
            age = todayYear - birthYear;

            if (todayMonth < birthMonth - 1){
              age--;
            }

            if (birthMonth - 1 == todayMonth && todayDay < birthDay){
              age--;
            }

            return age;
          }

          var old = age(birthdayArray[0], birthdayArray[1], birthdayArray[2]);

          return '<span>'
                + '<a href="/player/' + suggestion.id + '/' + suggestion.first_name.toLowerCase() + '-' + suggestion.last_name.toLowerCase() + '">'
                +   '<div class="media">'
                +     '<div class="media-left">'
                +       '<img class="media-object" src="/imagecache/small/' + suggestion.image_filename + '">'
                +     '</div>'
                +     '<div class="media-body">'
                +       '<p>' + suggestion._highlightResult.first_name.value + " " + suggestion._highlightResult.last_name.value + '<small> ' + old + ' years</small>' + '</p>'
                +       '<small> ' + suggestion.nationality + ' '+ suggestion.position + '</small>'
                +     '</div>'
                +   '</div>'
                + '</a>'
                +'</span>';
        }
      }
    },
    {
      source: autocomplete.sources.hits(videos, { hitsPerPage: 5 }),
      displayKey: 'title',
      templates: {
        header: '<div class="aa-suggestions-category"><span>Videos</span></div>',
        suggestion: function(suggestion) {
          timeAgo();
          return '<span>'
                +  '<a href="/player/video/' + suggestion.uid + '/' + suggestion.player_name.toLowerCase() + '-' + suggestion.player_surname.toLowerCase() + '">'
                +    '<div class="media">'
                +      '<img class="d-flex mr-3" src="https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/videos.football-talents.com/' + suggestion.video_id + '_1.jpg">'
                +      '<div class="media-body">'
                +        '<p>' + suggestion._highlightResult.title.value + ' <small class="timeago" title="' + suggestion.created_at + '">' + suggestion.created_at + '</small>' + '</p>'
                +        '<small> ' + suggestion._highlightResult.player_name.value + " " + suggestion._highlightResult.player_surname.value + '</small>'
                +      '</div>'
                +    '</div>'
                +  '</a>'
                +'</span>';
        }
      }
    }
]).on('autocomplete:updated', function(event, suggestion, dataset) {
  var timeagoTimeout;
  clearTimeout(timeagoTimeout);
  timeAgo();
  timeagoTimeout = setTimeout(timeAgo, 60000);
});
```

And this is the `timeago.js`

```
var timeAgo = function(selector) {

    var templates = {
        prefix: "",
        suffix: " ago",
        seconds: "less than a minute",
        minute: "about a minute",
        minutes: "%d minutes",
        hour: "about an hour",
        hours: "about %d hours",
        day: "a day",
        days: "%d days",
        month: "about a month",
        months: "%d months",
        year: "about a year",
        years: "%d years"
    };
    var template = function (t, n) {
        return templates[t] && templates[t].replace(/%d/i, Math.abs(Math.round(n)));
    };

    var timer = function (time) {
        if (!time) return;
        time = time.replace(/\.\d+/, ""); // remove milliseconds
        time = time.replace(/-/, "/").replace(/-/, "/");
        time = time.replace(/T/, " ").replace(/Z/, " UTC");
        time = time.replace(/([\+\-]\d\d)\:?(\d\d)/, " $1$2"); // -04:00 -> -0400
        time = new Date(time * 1000 || time);

        var now = new Date();
        var seconds = ((now.getTime() - time) * .001) >> 0;
        var minutes = seconds / 60;
        var hours = minutes / 60;
        var days = hours / 24;
        var years = days / 365;

        return templates.prefix + (
        seconds < 45 && template('seconds', seconds) || seconds < 90 && template('minute', 1) || minutes < 45 && template('minutes', minutes) || minutes < 90 && template('hour', 1) || hours < 24 && template('hours', hours) || hours < 42 && template('day', 1) || days < 30 && template('days', days) || days < 45 && template('month', 1) || days < 365 && template('months', days / 30) || years < 1.5 && template('year', 1) || template('years', years)) + templates.suffix;
    };

    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('timeago');
    for (var i in elements) {
        var $this = elements[i];
        if (typeof $this === 'object') {
            $this.innerHTML = timer($this.getAttribute('title') || $this.getAttribute('datetime'));
        }
    }
    // update time every minute
    setTimeout(timeAgo, 60000);
};
```

If I import them in html like shown below, then everything works fine:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/timeago.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/autocomplete.js') }}"></script>
```

But, if I try to bundle them with other files in my app.js:

```
require('./bootstrap');
require('./slider');
require('./search-form');
require('./timeago');
require('./autocomplete');
```

Then, I get the error:

> autocomplete.js?fbbb:20 Uncaught ReferenceError: todayDate is not
>   defined
>       at age (eval at  (app.js:606), :20:19)
>       at suggestion (eval at  (app.js:606), :37:17)
>       at a (autocomplete.min.js:7)
>       at Object.a.exports.z.map (autocomplete.min.js:6)
>       at d (autocomplete.min.js:7)
>       at d._render (autocomplete.min.js:7)
>       at d.b (autocomplete.min.js:7)
>       at Object.callback (autocomplete.min.js:7)
>       at algoliasearch.min.js:3 age @ autocomplete.js?fbbb:20 suggestion @ autocomplete.js?fbbb:37 a @ autocomplete.min.js:7 a.exports.z.map @
>   autocomplete.min.js:6 d @ autocomplete.min.js:7
>   _render @ autocomplete.min.js:7 b @ autocomplete.min.js:7 (anonymous) @ autocomplete.min.js:7 (anonymous) @ algoliasearch.min.js:3
>   setTimeout (async) t.exports @ algoliasearch.min.js:3 (anonymous) @
>   algoliasearch.min.js:3 Promise resolved (async) n._jsonRequest @
>   algoliasearch.min.js:3 r._search @ algoliasearch.min.js:3 (anonymous)
>   @ algoliasearch.min.js:3 c @ autocomplete.min.js:7 update @
>   autocomplete.min.js:7 b @ autocomplete.min.js:7 c @
>   autocomplete.min.js:6 a.exports.z.each @ autocomplete.min.js:6 f.each
>   @ autocomplete.min.js:6 update @ autocomplete.min.js:7
>   _onQueryChanged @ autocomplete.min.js:7 d @ autocomplete.min.js:7 h @ autocomplete.min.js:7
>   _checkInputValue @ autocomplete.min.js:7
>   _onInput @ autocomplete.min.js:7 f @ autocomplete.min.js:6 d.proxy @ autocomplete.min.js:6 autocomplete.js?fbbb:48 Uncaught ReferenceError:
>   timeAgo is not defined
>       at suggestion (eval at  (app.js:606), :48:7)
>       at a (autocomplete.min.js:7)
>       at Object.a.exports.z.map (autocomplete.min.js:6)
>       at d (autocomplete.min.js:7)
>       at d._render (autocomplete.min.js:7)
>       at d.b (autocomplete.min.js:7)
>       at Object.callback (autocomplete.min.js:7)
>       at algoliasearch.min.js:3 suggestion @ autocomplete.js?fbbb:48 a @ autocomplete.min.js:7 a.exports.z.map @ autocomplete.min.js:6 d @
>   autocomplete.min.js:7
>   _render @ autocomplete.min.js:7 b @ autocomplete.min.js:7 (anonymous) @ autocomplete.min.js:7 (anonymous) @ algoliasearch.min.js:3
>   setTimeout (async) t.exports @ algoliasearch.min.js:3 (anonymous) @
>   algoliasearch.min.js:3 Promise resolved (async) n._jsonRequest @
>   algoliasearch.min.js:3 r._search @ algoliasearch.min.js:3 (anonymous)
>   @ algoliasearch.min.js:3 c @ autocomplete.min.js:7 update @
>   autocomplete.min.js:7 b @ autocomplete.min.js:7 c @
>   autocomplete.min.js:6 a.exports.z.each @ autocomplete.min.js:6 f.each
>   @ autocomplete.min.js:6 update @ autocomplete.min.js:7
>   _onQueryChanged @ autocomplete.min.js:7 d @ autocomplete.min.js:7 h @ autocomplete.min.js:7
>   _checkInputValue @ autocomplete.min.js:7
>   _onInput @ autocomplete.min.js:7 f @ autocomplete.min.js:6 d.proxy @ autocomplete.min.js:6 autocomplete.js?fbbb:55 Uncaught ReferenceError:
>   timeAgo is not defined
>       at HTMLInputElement.eval (eval at  (app.js:606), :55:3)
>       at HTMLInputElement.d.proxy (autocomplete.min.js:6)
>       at HTMLInputElement. (autocomplete.min.js:6)
>       at autocomplete.min.js:6
>       at p.every ()
>       at p.each (autocomplete.min.js:6)
>       at p.a.exports.b.fn.trigger (autocomplete.min.js:6)
>       at d.trigger (autocomplete.min.js:7)
>       at d._onDatasetRendered (autocomplete.min.js:6)
>       at d (autocomplete.min.js:7) (anonymous) @ autocomplete.js?fbbb:55 d.proxy @ autocomplete.min.js:6 (anonymous) @ autocomplete.min.js:6
>   (anonymous) @ autocomplete.min.js:6 each @ autocomplete.min.js:6
>   a.exports.b.fn.trigger @ autocomplete.min.js:6 trigger @
>   autocomplete.min.js:7
>   _onDatasetRendered @ autocomplete.min.js:6 d @ autocomplete.min.js:7 f.run @ autocomplete.min.js:7 e @ autocomplete.min.js:7 characterData
>   (async) (anonymous) @ autocomplete.min.js:7 g @ autocomplete.min.js:7
>   h @ autocomplete.min.js:7
>   _onRendered @ autocomplete.min.js:7 d @ autocomplete.min.js:7 h @ autocomplete.min.js:7 clear @ autocomplete.min.js:7 a @
>   autocomplete.min.js:7 c @ autocomplete.min.js:6 a.exports.z.each @
>   autocomplete.min.js:6 f.each @ autocomplete.min.js:6 empty @
>   autocomplete.min.js:7
>   _onBlurred @ autocomplete.min.js:6 d @ autocomplete.min.js:7 h @ autocomplete.min.js:7
>   _onBlur @ autocomplete.min.js:7 f @ autocomplete.min.js:6 d.proxy @ autocomplete.min.js:6 autocomplete.js?fbbb:55 Uncaught ReferenceError:
>   timeAgo is not defined
>       at HTMLInputElement.eval (eval at  (app.js:606), :55:3)
>       at HTMLInputElement.d.proxy (autocomplete.min.js:6)
>       at HTMLInputElement. (autocomplete.min.js:6)
>       at autocomplete.min.js:6
>       at p.every ()
>       at p.each (autocomplete.min.js:6)
>       at p.a.exports.b.fn.trigger (autocomplete.min.js:6)
>       at d.trigger (autocomplete.min.js:7)
>       at d._onDatasetRendered (autocomplete.min.js:6)
>       at d (autocomplete.min.js:7)

Comment: Would you kindly post your route that serves the page that we're working with?

Comment: I am developing locally

Comment: Then why do you have an app.js? Aren't you using a nodejs server?

Comment: no, I am not, my backend is built with laravel, I am just using node for modules

Comment: missed var? `var todayDate = new Date();`

Comment: @emed that was actually it, I also put the the whole timeAgo function above the autocomplete to the same file, and then it worked